# Composite Shims & Liquid Nails

Tags: adhesive

I used Timberwolf Composite Shims with Liquid Nails Heavy Duty Construction Adhesive and Liquid Nails Subfloor Adhesive. I didn't read the Liquid Nails instructions, until after I used the products (...brilliant...) and they recommend not using them with plastic, vinyl or composite lumber.

I've contacted Liquid Nails and I'm awaiting their reply.

The shims are made out of HDPE (milk jugs) and cellulose (wood fiber).

Are the shims safe to use with Liquid Nails? Has anyone used composite shims with Liquid Nails? Will they react/weaken? What should I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received replies from both companies.

Liquid Nails wrote, "They will not react per say but there is a good chance they will not adhere properly. Unfortunately there is nothing that we can recommend for HDPE because nothing will adhere."

True Line Mold, the manufacturers of Timberwolf Composite Shims replied, "What we have found with Liquid Nails and Elmers Glue-All Max is that they will adhere to the shims, but require a longer cure time to completely set-up. Thus why I believe the Liquid Nails states not recommended for use with plastic, vinyl or composite lumber because most applications do not allow for an extended cure time. You should not see any degradation in the shims, it may simply be a case of the adhesive not being as strong of a bond as you desire provided on the cure time."